# Lambda query is throwing object does not contains error while coming dynamic type of data via `MOQ` setup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dynamic, lambda, moq

***Lambda query is throwing object does not contains error while coming dynamic type of data via `MOQ` setup***

---

**test Method:**

```
 [Fact]
        public void GetMainTypeList()
        {
            var mockColorsRepository = MoqHelper.CreateInstanceOfIMock<IColorsRepository>();
          mockColorsRepository.Setup(rep => rep.GetMainTypeList(It.IsAny<Colour>())).Returns((Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<dynamic>>(new[] { new { DoorCode = "001", MainTypeCode = "1" }, new { DoorCode = "002", MainTypeCode = "2" } })));
            ColorsValidator colorsValidator = new ColorsValidator(mockColorsRepository.Object);
            CoCApiResponse response = colorsValidator.GetMainTypeList(mockColorsRepository.Object);
            Assert.Equal(1, response.ResultCode);
        }
```

**Business class method(class name is ColourValidator) :**

```
 public CoCBaseCollection<string> GetMainTypeList()
        {
            CoCBaseCollection<string> mtlst = new CoCBaseCollection<string>();
            var carlist = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)vehrep.GetMainTypeList().Result;
            mtlst.AddItems(carlist.Select(cl => (string)cl.MainTypeCode).Where(mt => mt != null).Distinct().ToList());
            return mtlst;
        }
```

I am did MOQ setup for my repository call which is getting data from database in real time also setup a mock data which is getting data via Moq while  unit testing for this below line

### Repository Call

> `var carlist = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)vehrep.GetMainTypeList().Result;// repository call`

### Problem

```
mtlst.AddItems(carlist.Select(cl => (string)cl.MainTypeCode).Where(mt => 
mt != null).Distinct().ToList());// this code is not working while setup 
mock data in return function of `Moq.Setup`
```

The above code is working if am giving `carlist` data manually like below,

```
var carlist = Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<dynamic>>(new[] { new { DoorCode 
= "001", MainTypeCode = "1" }, new { DoorCode = "002", MainTypeCode 
= "2" } }).Result;
```

but That(repository call) code not working if am giving this same mock data  via `MOQ` setup response, like this

```
mockColorsRepository.Setup(rep => rep.GetMainTypeList(It.IsAny<Colour>
())).Returns((Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<dynamic>>(new[] { new { DoorCode 
= "001", MainTypeCode = "1" }, new { DoorCode = "002", MainTypeCode 
= "2" } })));
```

### Error:

And it is showing this below error

[image]

> **Note:** Am using this same code for some other test methods which is working perfectly. But this problem only happens when I am using `dynamic` type instead of Business entity.

Comment: What if using `object`?

Comment: @zcui93 I didn't check it.  previous developers are using dynamic data type for lot of repository methods. So I can't change the type dynamic to object or business entity.

Comment: @zcui93 I tried now. The same problem occurred :( . very critical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the image link at office right now, so don't know what's the error / not working reason.

---

I started to wonder the need of `dynamic` at all.

But by looking at your business class method, the casting to `IEnumerable<dynamic>` is not needed at all I think, by just using anonymous type. i.e. the following should still work

```
var carlist = vehrep.GetMainTypeList().Result; // <-- remove the cast still work
mtlst.AddItems(carlist.Select(cl => (string)cl.MainTypeCode).Where(mt => mt != null).Distinct().ToList());
```

At the same time, I think your don't necessarily need to return `(IEnumerable<dynamic>)` for your `Task`, as the following code still works

```
Task.FromResult(new[]  { new { DoorCode
    = "001", MainTypeCode = "1" }, new { DoorCode = "002", MainTypeCode
    = "2" }}).Result
```

which means that for your moq setup, this should work

```
mockColorsRepository.Setup(rep => rep.GetMainTypeList(It.IsAny<Colour>
    ())).Returns((Task.FromResult(new[] { new { DoorCode          // <-- Remove type
    = "001", MainTypeCode = "1" }, new { DoorCode = "002", MainTypeCode
    = "2" } })));
```

Comment: `Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> GetColorsList();` this is  my method in interface for repository . If am removing type. it will throwing error .

Comment: As I said, I can't see your error picture, so no idea what's your problem. Anyway, so I guess you also tried `Task.FromResult((IEnumerable<dynamic>) new[] { new { DoorCod`

Comment: The error is object does not contains a definition for maintypecode

Comment: My suggestion is really, you need to seriously consider whether your code base is overusing `dynamic` I guess. Providing solid class type for repository doesn't hurt.

Comment: That's good idea! That is also working fine for my side. But previous developer has to be use  lot of dynamic type instead of using business entity classes. So I couldn't change it all over project. That's why am thinking it crucial moment for this project :(

Comment: Just for clarity, the error you saw happens within `GetMainTypeList`, not during Moq setup?

Comment: If that's the case, please debug the unit test and see what's the actual object there.